# Is it safe to replace localhost.localdomain with real domain?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, php, sendmail

I am configuring a ubuntu server, so I am using `sendmail` to use PHP mail function. However it keeps sending email to the spam folder of inbox. I'm just trying to make the emails go to inbox instead of the spam folder.

It has following line in the /etc/hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost.localdomain test1
```

test1 is the host name. Should I change the localhost.localdomain to `mydomain.com`? Is it safe to use real domain name in the hosts file or will it cause some email spam problem? (I did read somewhere, not sure if I understood correctly.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't your problem. You likely have not configured some combination of the following: MX Records, DKIM/SPF Records, Reverse DNS, etc.

Mail isn't as simple as "install MTA, send email."